# Legal permits required for trekking in Canada

Tags: trekking, legality, canada, permits

I will be travelling to Canada for a business trip, and I can spare a weekend in between my schedule. I'd be keen to trek/hike near Vancouver, and I have banked upon hiking [The Stawamus Chief](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stawamus_Chief). As I'll be there as a technocrat, am I legally allowed to hike in Canada? Or do I have to comply to any legal procedures?

Comment: You might wanna consider discussing the same with the clients that you're gonna see?

Comment: You're allowed to do tourist things on a business trip, if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

National parks tend to be absolutely open to anyone, their goal being to allow  [public enjoyment without compromising the area for future generations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Parks_of_Canada).

From the park's own [website](http://www.env.gov.bc.ca/bcparks/permits/):

> A permit is not required for front-country camping, hiking, moorage,
>   etc. in most parks. Campsite reservations are accepted at many
>   front-country parks.

To be absolutely sure, you could try [contacting](http://www.env.gov.bc.ca/bcparks/info/feedback.html) the park itself.

As a bonus, [this page](http://www.env.gov.bc.ca/bcparks/explore/parkpgs/stawamus/) has a lot of general information related to your planned hike. The only fees are for camping!

Comment: Yep, no need to get a permit to climb the Chief.  Have fun!